# Error in requesting track for url for SPTTrack object

Tags: spotify-app

I am trying to get SPTTrack object from url using Spotify iOS SKD v10beta.
Somehow, it returns an error, like :

```
Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk Code=102 "No registered class for type 'artist'" UserInfo=0x7a644700 {NSLocalizedDescription=No registered class for type 'artist'}
```

Strange thing, that it has worked previously. I have found similar problem in getting the user.

What this error is related to? I have removed/added,linked spotify framework multiple times.
Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error occurred because ObjC was not present at **Other Linker Flags** in frameworks/libraries/targets/project.

Comment: Nice  you saved a lot of time